# How to change the location automatically of a div when it's right of left side element is removed from document

Tags: position

Here i have a probs,

i wanna sift automatically a div when it's right side element is removed from document. 
let all the elements are start from the right to left side like 
D C B A.
in above example A is the first Div B is Second and so on. what i want that when i removed element A, the element  B that was after A will be shift automatically at the position of a.

please tell me something if anyone have any idea about it.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign div align="right" to all div elements. When one div is deleted all other will shift to right automatic.
I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this effect you can use the css `float: right;`:

```
<div id='A' style='float:right;'>A</div>
<div id='B' style='float:right;'>B</div>
<div id='C' style='float:right;'>C</div>
```

If you remove A from the DOM then B will float automaticly to the right.

Take a look to SELFhtml too:

http://de.selfhtml.org/navigation/suche/index.htm?Suchanfrage=float

To do the removal via javascript you could use jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#A').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks dear, 
i applied this attributes to all divs But it's not working.

i think to work it the page should be refreshed but i am removing element by javascript so .....

Comment: I postet a suggestion how to hide it via jQuery. This works with the floating as well.

Comment: nops dear i dont want that, removing of element is running successfully but after removing the first div, removing div's should be shifted to right but its not going. like this
let 
E D C B A   all of the are div's


now if i removed a then it should be like this
E D C B
and now if i removed c then

E D B.

Comment: Ok, then how do you perform the removal? Can you post some code to test your problem?

Comment: nothing special. 
i only called a function in which the div id is passed as a parameter and the i found its parent element after that just removeChild.

Comment: Reply me soon dear, i really need of it too much.

Comment: Please post some code so we can reproduce your problem. The code above should already do what you described.